# Wrapping Content In Shapes With CSS

Tags: css, web

I am trying to wrap a text inside a specific shape, but it doesn't work out.

```
.shape {   
    -webkit-hyphens: manual;  
    -webkit-shape-inside: polygon(0px 0px, 0 300px, 300px 300px);  
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5cd1og0p/

Is there anything that I should do ?

More specific, I am trying to wrap a text around a specific shape (polygone)

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/

Comment: `shape-inside` has been removed from the spec. It should be coming back in the future: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes-2/#shape-inside-property

Comment: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan Is this related to my question

Comment: @WhiteLine I read that article to get started, check the code.

Comment: CSS Shapes are currently supported only in Webkit Nightly and Chrome Canary :) http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101

Comment: yes it is absolutely related.

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan Can you expalin ?